# Canvas Paint, Bezier Curve, Arc Highest point

Tags: android, canvas, path, curve

I'm having some struggle with the mathematics of what I'm trying to accomplish, I have a bezier curve and Im trying to draw a circle on its highest peak, when its a straight horizontal line, its fine, but once I curved the line (cubicTo) and using PathMeasure.getPosTan(..), it moves away from the highest peak. Please see the attached Image and codes below

[image: straight Line]

[image: curved line]

```
arcPath.cubicTo(0f, height.toFloat(), mArcPeakX, mArcPeakY, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat())
```

and the part that does the painting of circles

```
arcPathMeasure.getPosTan(mArcPeakX, positionArray, null)

canvas.drawCircle(0f, height.toFloat(), 10f, paint)
canvas.drawCircle(positionArray[0],  positionArray[1], 10f, paint)
canvas.drawCircle(width.toFloat(), height.toFloat(), 10f, paint)
```

I dont know what math am i missing, but once the line is curved, the circle advances and is not painted on the peak of the arc/curve.

Comment: oh my ... I have no idea, where to start with that. but ill try anyway, or Ill try to find some sample codes, where there is a curve, and a shape is drawn on every (x,y) of the cubic

Comment: or if you need some maths then see https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#extremities

Comment: And you really need maths, here. You need to find the maximum of your curve by finding the roots of the derivative of your Bezier function. Thankfully, Bezier functions are really dumb sums of terms, and getting the derivative is basically zero work (https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#derivatives). Find the time values for which the derivative is zero (noting that there might be more than one) and you're basically done.